# How to get checkbox selected raw in data grid dev express winform

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, devexpress, gridcontrol

I get all data from db.i add checkbox colmn in grid manually.if i select checkbox .i want value of checked raw from data grid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Refer below example:
int[] rowHandles = this.gridView.GetSelectedRows();  
if (rowHandles == null || rowHandles.Length == 0)  
        return;  
foreach (int rowHandle in rowHandles)  
{  
    DataRow row = 
                this.gridView.GetDataRow(rowHandle);  
    if (row != null)  
    {  
           var name = row["NAME"].ToString();
    }  
}
```